# Using Mongo db to create a new user

Tags: sql, mongodb

I'm new to database structures and I've been learning it for a few weeks now. Today I encountered an error while trying to add a new user using my command prompt.

Heres the code:

```
db.createUSer( { user: "Haven", pwd: passwordPrompt(), 
   roles: [{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "joshua"}, "readWriteAnyDatabase"]})
```

Here's the error I get:

> uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: Error preflighting UTF-8 conversion: U_STRING_NOT_TERMINATED_WARNING :
> _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
> DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1367:11

Comment: Apart from typo `db.createUser` instead of `db.createUSer` the command looks OK.

Comment: Role `{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "joshua"}` does not make any sense. Roles which are created in other database than `admin` can only include privileges that apply to its database and can only inherit from other roles in its database. Thus `...AnyDatabase` roles make only sense when used on database `admin`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I set an empty password, but ok when not empty are you just hitting return at the passwordPrompt() ?

```
test> use mytest-db
switched to db mytest-db
mytest-db> db.createUser({"user":"foobar", "pwd":"", "roles": ["readWrite"]})
MongoServerError: Error preflighting UTF-8 conversion: U_STRING_NOT_TERMINATED_WARNING
mytest-db> db.createUser({"user":"foobar", "pwd":"mysecret", "roles": ["readWrite"]})
{ ok: 1 }
```